# Firebase "addValueEventListener" being called even if offline

Tags: java, android

I made an app of current Metal Rates of my city. I keep metal rates updated every few hours. I've an TextView that gets updated with current Time and Date if and only if new Rate is updated(by me in console). Now,the problem is, even if the app is offline,my TextView gets updated with current time..meaning that the addValueEventListener is active and listening. I don't want the TextView to be updated if app is offline or until and unless updated manually by me. This is my code-

```
 mFirebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("metals").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               String ratesteel= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

               tvsteelrate.setText(ratesteel);

     //getting notification of updated price
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("ST")
                    .setContentText("Updated")
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build());
            count++;


            Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c);
            mydate.setText(formattedDate);

            }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
        }
    });


}
```

How can I disable TextView being updated if app is offline or is not updated?

Comment: did you enable firebase offline capabilities? > https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Yes i did..still same.

Comment: So you enabled offline and are asking why it's happening? Clarify if you disabled it and still have the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to only execute when you call it, use `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`

```
mFirebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("metals").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         // do your stuff here
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Still not working..my textview is updated upon opening app even if it's offline

Comment: @Mukesh then the piece of code you shared is not helpful enough. Add more details of where, how, and when the snippet is executed